# Special Distance function

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

This is my first post. I am not a professional mathematician, but there is a question that is relevant to the work I am doing. (Please forgive me if I make any errors)

Say I got a vector $\vec{x}=(x_0,x_1,...,x_n)$ and another one $\vec{y}=(y_0,y_1,...,y_n)$ , we all know about the euclidean distance. In the case that $x_i=y_i \, \forall{i}$ then the distance is 0.

Now imagine another vector $\vec{z}=(x_2,...x_n,x_0,x_1)$. As you can see the elements of the vector are the same as with $\vec{x}$, just rotated somehow.

My question is, can we define a *distance function* that will consider a distance 0 for all different permutations where the order is maintained of the vector x and a distance other than 0 for other vectors?

Edit: to make things clearer. My apologies

Comment: Depends on what you mean by distance. The general definition requires $d(x,y)\ge 0$ with equality if and only if $x=y$.

Comment: Alright, let's call it something different then. Can we define a function that will give us $f(x,y)=0$ for the condition stated above?

Comment: And you want this condition to be any permutation, or just cyclic permutations?

Comment: You certainly can define such a function: let $f(\vec x,\vec y)=0$ if $\vec x$ is a permutation of $\vec y$, and let it be the euclidean distance otherwise. Done!

Comment: @helloworld112358 The order of the elements have to be maintained.

Comment: @MatthewConroy This would not necessarily satisfy the triangle inequality - but not sure that is necessary.

Comment: @helloworld112358 Yes, it wouldn't satisfy a lot of things.  The OP hasn't really made clear what they want. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the coordinates of the two vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ first and then use the euclidean distance.

Comment: umm, that defeats the purpose. You see in my domain problem the dimensions of the vector are kind of large. And you don't know where exactly the original start $x_0$ is. So it helps if I can define a function that just takes the two vectors and give a value

Comment: @KansaiRobot What Somos suggests does take two vectors and give a value.  You need to make your problem clearer.

Comment: The original author comments that "The order of the elements have to be maintained." That was not what the original question asked for when it states "for all different permutations of the vector x". However, if you restrict to only circular shifts, then you just circular shift so that the minimum element comes first.

Comment: Again, the original question said nothing about large dimensions. Since you have to go thru all the elements in a vector to process them, it is not more costly to scan them first to find the minimal element.